# Approach to providing read-access to logs

Tags: linux, unix, logging, logstash

We have many servers (Dev, Integration, PT etc.) and there are a lot of tomcats running on each server. Our application is divided into components and each tomcat runs with the name of a specific component. For ex., we have security-tomcat running as *security* user, search-tomcat running as *search* user and so on.

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 security security  20 Sep 27 10:28 security-tomcat
drwxr-xr-x 1 search   search    27 Sep 27 10:31 search-tomcat
```

Often, when there are issues in any component, dev and testing guys ask for read-access to the log files of Tomcat server. What we do is simply add the user to the group which is associated with the given component. For ex.,

```
security:x:319:tom,dick,harry
```

I know that we can ‘chmod o+r’ sort of thing instead of adding users to the group. All that is fine but I feel there must be a better way. I am looking for some tool which can provide a GUI sort of thing where users could simply log in and from some drop-down list, select the environment (Dev, Integration, PT) and then select the log (such as server.log, catalina.out etc.), and view it. That way I can have a centralized view for logs present on different instances. This will also help reduce the clutter in the /etc/group file and make the overall log management cleaner.

Is *Logstash* meant for this kind of scenario? I just had a glance at Logstash and I also saw few mins of one of the videos on Youtube by its founder but I got the feeling that that’s not really the tool I’m looking for. Please correct me if it can be used in my scenario. I would really appreciate if someone can suggest some tool which is meant for the issue I’ve stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check the ELK product ( Logstash, Elasticsearch, Kibana) as it is the leading open source solution and it will provide you centralized access to your log files. It is a product that was built in order to provide the solution for your exact problem and it is doing it quite well.

All you will need is to configure a filter in Logstash that will add a field with the environment name and usually the log file name will already be provided by default. Using these fields you will be able to filter your data and create great graphs, tables and share them for others to use using Kibana.

You can check my website: [logs101.com](http://logs101.com) for more information about centralized logging solutions and contact me if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tom. From what i understood, it seems Logstash provides parsed output based on the filter we provide. What i am looking for is a GUI where one could select the log (fetched from several machines) and simply view the whole log file. Is Logstash meant for that purpose?

Comment: Logstash by itself is only one component in the whole operation and it will not provide you this ability. What you should do is to send all you logs into elasticsearch (the database) and then using Kibana (the client) you will be able to see all your logs in one, easy to use, web interface. 

Logstash has an output to send data into elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Tom! I think it will take some time for me to evaluate ELK stack. Once i'm done, i'll update. By the way, can you think of any other alternative for my issue?